# Different use of gamma factor in time dilation in Griffith's 4th edition

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation

I am a bit confused about the format chosen by D. J. Griffith's in his book "*Introduction to Electrodynamics, 4th Edition (International Edition)*" in chapter 12 on "*Electrodynamics and Relativity*". On **page 515** he has the equation:

$$\Delta \bar{t} = \sqrt{1-v^{2}/c^{2}}\Delta t = \frac{1}{\gamma}\Delta t$$

and similarly on **page 522** he has the two equivalent forms

$$\Delta t = \gamma\Delta \bar{t}$$
$$\Delta \bar{t} = \frac{1}{\gamma}\Delta t$$

where in all cases $\gamma \equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^{2}/c^{2}}}$ as defined on page 522.

Now my question, why does this not match all other definitions I find? Firstly it doesn't even match with the examples that Griffiths provides. For example in his **example 12.1** on **page 511-512** the used equation is $$t'=\gamma t$$

Similarly in his **problem 12.7** on **page 514** the correct solution (verified with the instructor's manual) is to use $$t'=\gamma t$$

This is identical to what [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation) also shows: $\Delta \bar{t} = \frac{\Delta t}{\sqrt{1-v^{2}/c^{2}}}$.

So in summary it seems to me that the notation used by Griffith's is either inconsistent or just wrong. There is however a much larger chance, that I am simply missing something obvious. So please enlighten me. Thanks!

Comment: It’s the same $\gamma$. It’s more likely that those passages define t and decorated-t differently. It will take a little time to consult those sections fully.

Comment: It might help to think of $\gamma$ as the hyperbolic-cosine $\cosh\theta$, which is the ratio of sides (adjacent-to-$\theta$)/(hypotenuse, opposite the Minkowski-right-angle) in Minkowski-right-triangle. Draw a Spacetime diagram… don’t just rely on symbols and formulas.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. That was indeed my first thought also. It does however seem that Griffith's is consistent with using an overbar to denote measurements made on the moving system. He explicitly mentions this on page 511, and it seems to be valid for all subsequent examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I confirm your equations for p. 515 (longitudinal light clock in a boxcar)
$$\Delta \bar{t} = \sqrt{1-v^{2}/c^{2}}\Delta t = \frac{1}{\gamma}\Delta t$$
and
p. 522 (Example 12.4 on "how much time elapsed on a moving clock")
$$\Delta t = \gamma\Delta \bar{t}$$
$$ \Delta \bar{t} = \frac{1}{\gamma}\Delta t $$

However, I didn't find the equation you claim ( $t'=\gamma t$)

- example 12.1 on page 511-512
  but the example does say 
  "it [the muon] lives longer (than at rest) by a factor of $5/4$: $\frac{5}{4}\times (2\times 10^{-6})s = 2.5 \times 10^{-6}s$."

or

- problem 12.7 on page 514 (textbook and instructor solutions)

  but it does say (in the solutions) 
  "In the laboratory, the muon lasts $\gamma\tau=\frac{\tau}{\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}}$, where $\tau$ is the proper lifetime, $2\mu s$."

---

A set of spacetime diagrams will help justify all of Griffith's quoted equations.

for p.515 and p. 522, where $OS$ is the elapsed proper time on a moving clock,
we have $\displaystyle\gamma=\cosh\theta=\frac{ADJ}{HYP}=\frac{OT}{OS}=\frac{10}{8}=\frac{5}{4}$ (which we expect from $\displaystyle v/c=\tanh\theta=\frac{OPP}{ADJ}=\frac{TS}{OT}=\frac{6}{10}=\frac{3}{5}$).

So,
$$\displaystyle 8= OS \stackrel{\checkmark}{=} \frac{1}{\gamma}\ OT = \frac{4}{5} (10)$$

[image: RRGP-robphy-Griffiths515and522]

For p. 511-512, where $OS$ is the muon proper lifetime,
and $OT$ is the lab's measurement of that lifetime,
again with $v/c=\tanh\theta=3/5$ and thus $\gamma=\cosh\theta=5/4$

So, [again]
$$\displaystyle 2.0\mu s= OS \stackrel{\checkmark}{=} \frac{1}{\gamma}\ OT = \frac{4}{5} (2.5\mu s)$$

[image: RRGP-robphy-Griffiths511]

Finally, for Problem 12.7 on p. 514 (with the faster muon), where $OS$ is the muon proper lifetime,
and $OT$ is the lab's measurement of that lifetime,
with $\displaystyle TS=800{\rm m}=\frac{8}{3} c\cdot\mu s$
so that $\displaystyle \gamma v/c=\sinh\theta=\frac{OPP}{HYP}=\frac{TS}{OS}=\frac{8/3}{6/3}=\frac{4}{3}$
and thus, since $OS^2=OT^2-TS^2$, we have $\displaystyle OT=\frac{10}{3}\mu s$

so, that $\displaystyle v/c=\tanh\theta=\frac{OPP}{ADJ}=\frac{TS}{OT}=\frac{8/3}{10/3}=\frac{4}{5}$
and $\displaystyle  \gamma=\cosh\theta=\frac{ADJ}{HYP}=\frac{OT}{OS}=\frac{10/3}{6/3}=\frac{5}{3}$.

So, [again]
$$\displaystyle 2.0\mu s= OS \stackrel{\checkmark}{=} \frac{1}{\gamma}\ OT = \frac{3}{5} \left(\frac{10}{3}\mu s\right)$$

[image: RRGP-robphy-Griffith514]

---

**It seems to me that Griffiths is consistent in these sections you reference.**

In my opinion, using a spacetime diagram with named segments (like $OS$ and $OT$, as one might do in geometry) is clearer than just using algebraic formulae involving $\Delta t$ and $\Delta t'$ or $\Delta \bar t$, etc... without specific reference to endpoint-events.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for taking the time to give such a detailed explanation. I really appreciate it, and your examples have helped me to avoid such confusion in the future. I'll try to make a habit out of drawing the diagram out every time. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the book at hand but it's like that maybe because no frame is considered special in (special) relatively so both frame would see the other frames time being dilated.

Since they both see each other moving at velocity $v$, so each form of the formula i.e.
$$\Delta t = \gamma\Delta \bar{t}$$

and
$$\Delta \bar t = \gamma\Delta{t}$$

are valid depending on the frame of reference.